# Template engine: Include

Tags: php, templates, include

I'm creating my own template engine using PHP. The basic idea is that for each page (visible for users) there are unique template file with HTML extension. For example...

> users-list.php => users-list.html
>
> profile.php => profile.html
>
> about-us.php => about-us.html

I just made comments available in template files (actually HTML). Comments are visible before processed so real client won't see them, but developer would. Syntax is {* foo *}, and that's made up using regex's. Now I need something like...

```
{include "header.html"}
```

I don't know how to write it using code, but, imho, I need something like...

> 1) Match all {include "xxx"},
>
> 2) From matches took string between " and ",
>
> 3) Load files content in strings and add to correct place.

Comment: You might want to checkout what PHP smarty does before implement your own template engine (although myself is not a smarty fan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
 preg_replace_callback(
     '~{include "(.+?)"}~', 
     function($m) { return file_get_contents($m[1]) }, 
     $str);
```